# How can I center a button or some text inside of a div horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML that is part of a grid using display: table-cell. The width of the div is wider than the contents:

```
<div>123</div>
<div><button>1</button></div>
```

How can I enter the text and the button inside the larger div?

Comment: Show us what you had already tried. We are not your brownies

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.centeredFlex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 600px; /* whatever you want... */
  width: 100%;   /* whatever you want... */
}
```

```html
<div class="centeredFlex">
    <button>1</button>
</div>
```

Have a look at flexbox: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp!

Comment: Syam Pillai was faster, his solution is right though. Mine is just a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

`flex-box` is the best solution

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center; 
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100vh;
 background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Text at center</p>
 <button>button</button>
</div>
```

You can remove `align-items: center` if you don't want horizontal center and can remove `justify-content: center` you don't want vertical center